# HttpResponse with string returned by function gives 'str' object has no attribute 'has_header'

Tags: python, django, django-views

From my views.py the following example works:

```
def get_stats_file (request):
    ...
    stats_file = settings.PROJECT_ROOT + "my.stats.txt"
    return HttpResponse (stats_file)
```

The following gives the error shown below. The only difference is that instead of creating the stats_file string from inside the function, I do it in another function.

```
def get_absolute_path (filename):
    return settings.PROJECT_ROOT + filename

def get_stats_file (request):
    stats_file = get_absolute_path("my.stats.txt")
    return HttpResponse (stats_file)
```

ERROR:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://a.b.c.d:8000/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/

Django Version: 1.4.3
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'visualizer')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')

Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/amsaha/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/views.py" in get_port_info
  39.     stats_file = get_absolute_path("my.stats.txt")
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  90.         add_never_cache_headers(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/cache.py" in add_never_cache_headers
  129.     patch_response_headers(response, cache_timeout=-1)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/cache.py" in patch_response_headers
  119.     if not response.has_header('Last-Modified'):

Exception Type: AttributeError at /XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'has_header'
```

I must be doing some very simple mistake :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that's all the relevant code?

First, HttpResponse doesn't provide functionality to slurp up a given filename into a response. What you're saying is "give me a response with the body that is equal to the filename, not the contents of the file at that filename". If you'd like the actual content, you should do HttpResponse(open(filename).read(), content_type="mimetype of the file")

Second, the stacktrace seems to imply that you're returning a string from the view and *not* an HttpResponse instance, which leads me to believe that you haven't shared enough code for us to see what's going on.